# Solution of the linear differential equation: $\frac {dy}{dx} + P(x) \cdot y=Q(x)$. What is the error in this approach?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Derive the solution of the linear differential equation: $\frac {dy}{dx} + P(x) \cdot y=Q(x)$

Rewriting the given differential equation, we obtain: $(Py-Q) dx+1 \cdot dy=0$.

Let $M=Py-Q, N=1$. Then : $\dfrac {\partial M }{\partial y}=M_y=P$

and $\dfrac {\partial N}{\partial x}=N_x=0$.

Thus $\dfrac{M_y-N_x}{N}=P(x)$. Thus, the integrating factor is $I.F= e^{\int P dx}$. Therefore  $e^{\int P dx}(Py-Q) dx+e^{\int P dx} \cdot dy=0$ **is an exact differential equation.**

The solution of this exact differential equation is $\int_{\text {treat y as constant} } M dx + \int \text{terms in N not containing x}~~ dy= $ constant

$\implies \int e^{\int P dx}(Py-Q)~ dx + 0=c$

> $\implies y \int P~ e^{\int P dx}~dx = \int e^{\int P dx} Q ~dx + c.~$
>   **But the solution of the differential equation in almost every textbook is given as $\implies y e^{\int P dx}~dx = \int e^{\int P dx} Q ~dx + c$**

What is the error in the above steps. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What is the $I$ here?

Comment: Is it possible that the second $dx$ in the first member of the last equality you have written should not be there? If that is the case, I think both expressions of the solution are equivalent.

Comment: @Nick Which $I$ are you talking about? is it the $I.F$?

Comment: @ABC I believe it should be there if one goes step by step.

Comment: @Isham The solution of an exact differential equation is $\int_{\text {treat y as constant} } M dx + \int \text{terms in N not containing x}~~ dy= $ constant

Comment: @MathMan But the $dx$ in the last equality "does not have its corresponding integral sign"

Comment: @ABC I am sorry, Could you please pin point which one exactly?

Comment: @MathMan In the coloured box there are two equalities. I am referring to the second one. In its first member there is an extra $dx$ I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\implies \int e^{\int P dx}(Py-Q)~ dx + 0=c$$
$$ \int e^{\int P dx}Pydx-\int e^{\int P dx}Qdx=c$$
$$ y\int e^{\int P dx}Pdx-\int e^{\int P dx}Qdx=c$$
you have a derivative in the first integral:
$$ y e^{\int P dx}-\int e^{\int P dx}Qdx=c$$
Therefore:
$$ y e^{\int P dx}=\int e^{\int P dx}Qdx+c$$

Comment: Thanks. Got it.

Comment: yw @MathMan your formula is correct it's just another formulation.